# Conditional Kullback Divergence

Tags: inequality, information-theory

Let X be a discrete random variable drawn according to probability
mass function $p(x)$ over alphabet $X$ , and let random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ take value in alphabet $Y$ with probability $p_1(y)$ and $p_2(y)$, respectively. The divergence and conditional divergence in this notation are: [image]

Can conditioning never reduce or never increase the divergence, or none of the above?

I have information that conditioning increases KL divergence, but have no clue how to show this information. Also, I am not sure if I can say $p(x)p_1(y|x)= p_1(x,y)$.

Any hints, or tips?

Comment: "Conditional Bullkack"?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the notation $D(P_{Y|X}\|Q_{Y|X}|P_X),$ since this makes the law over $X$ explicit.

For a pair of laws $P_{XY},Q_{XY},$ the chain rule for KL divergence is $$ D(P_{XY}\|Q_{XY}) = D(P_X\|Q_X) + D(P_{Y|X}\|Q_{Y|X}|P_X).$$

Now, if $P_X = Q_X$ as in the question, then the first term is $0$. But exchanging the role of $X$ and $Y$, we can also write  $$ D(P_{XY}\|Q_{XY}) = D(P_Y\|Q_Y) + D(P_{X|Y}\|Q_{X|Y}|P_Y), $$ and the final term here must be nonnegative (why?). We can thus infer that $$ D(P_Y\|Q_Y) \le D(P_{XY}\|Q_{XY}) = D(P_{Y|X}\|Q_{Y|X}|P_X).$$

Comment: Can we interpret this result intuitively? Also, if I want to use the notation in the question, can I subtract the two expressions, and use Jensen's inequality to prove the claim?

Thanks! I voted up for the answer!

Comment: I think maybe via Chernoff-Stein? (See [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10704/lec22-errexp.pdf) for background). Suppose I generate data in a two step way: First draw $X^n \sim P_{X}^{\otimes n}$, and then push this through either the channel $P_{Y|X}$ or the channel $Q_{Y|X}$. Now, if I only gave you the data $Y^n,$ then the optimal missed detection error exponent for a fixed false alarm rate is $D(P_Y\|Q_Y)$. But if instead I gave you $(X^n,Y^n),$ then you can separately compute likelihood ratios for each realisation of $X$, and get the optimal rate $D(P_{Y|X}\|Q_{Y|X}|P_X)$

Comment: Of course, the latter must be larger (since you could always drop the $X^n$ information). However, it'd take some work to argue that the optimal rate in the second case _is_ the conditional divergence (but not too much, just some messing around with Neyman-Pearson). I should note though that my bias is towards statistical interpretations, there might be a coding one that is more immediate :)

Comment: I think re. the notation, you could just write the chain rule in an expanded way, where $D(P_{XY}\|Q_{XY})$ gets replaced by $D(P_1\|P_2)$ where $P_1(x,y) = p(x) \cdot p_1(y|x)$ and similarly $P_2(x,y)$. Then just expand things via the chain rule in two ways. You can of course subtract if you like, but I feel like that might be messier.